# MySql Query Optimization for parent child relationship

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, parent-child, union

I am in trouble with large database with one of my query which is obvious not correct and I am not good in database side so I am not sure what I can do to optimize this query. Below is my table structure and details what data I need to fetch.

User Table

```
UserID    UserName    UserRole    ParentID
  1        ABC1            2          0
  2        ABC2            2          0
  3        ABC3            2          1
  4        ABC4            2          1
  5        ABC5            2          2
```

Survey Table Structure

```
SurveryID     SurveyTitle      UserID
   1           S1                3
   2           S2                3
   3           S3                4
   4           S4                4
   3           S3                4
   4           S4                5
   3           S3                3
   4           S4                5
   3           S3                3
   4           S4                4
```

The users which don't have parentID are Supervisors and who has parentID are Sales persons under that Parent supervisor.

So, I want to get list of Supervisor with their sales person with number os surveys they did. Something like below.

```
SuperVisorName     SurveyCount 
ABC1                    10
     ABC3           4    
     ABC4           6

ABC2                     18
     ABC5           18
```

In our current system, we first get all supervisors and then look through all supervisors to get their sales person with their surveys.

This make query very slow thus, resulting timeout error. We have 40k records for survey right now and hoping to grow more than 100k.

I searched little on that and we found Union can help in this but I am not sure how to apply in my scenario ? I guess this should be a single query to accomplish said result ?

Please let me know if you have any questions. I would clarify those.

Will appreciate your help on this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: how do you get survey count ? by counting number userId from survey table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select 
   if(a.username is null, b.username, a.username) as username, 
   a.parentid, -----if(a.username is null, 0, a.parentid) parentid,  
   a.cnt       -----Replace above line if you want value to be 0 of parentId
from
   (select 
       parentid, 
       username,  
       count(*) cnt 
   from 
       tbl1 a 
   inner join 
       tbl2 b
   on 
       a.userid = b.userid
   group by 
       parentid, 
       username 
   with rollup) a
inner join
   tbl1 b
on 
   a.parentid = b.userid
```

**Results**:

```
| USERNAME | PARENTID | CNT |
-----------------------------
|     ABC3 |        1 |   4 |
|     ABC4 |        1 |   4 |
|     ABC1 |        1 |   8 |
|     ABC5 |        2 |   2 |
|     ABC2 |        2 |   2 |
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bffee/12)**

Comment: Excellent @Meherzad! Much more succinct than my answer. I'm going to remove mine to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Meherzad, Thanks for your answer. I am going to try this one soon and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok So, I got chance to play with your query. Seems I got one issue with this. I am not getting users who are supervisors. I am getting only child users who has parentID and not those who has parentID=0 (means they are supervisors). Any thoughts on it ?

Comment: To more clarify, Actual result would not have ABC1 & ABC2 records in the result as per your query. I am not sure how you get ParentID=1 & 2 even they don't have any parent ? Let me know if you have any question. Also, about survey count, yes I would count number of records.

Comment: ABC1 and ABC2 are the supervisors according to these sample records and survey count of supervisor's is equal to sum of subordinates survey count.. According to the fiddle `ABC1` is supervisor of 3 and 4 so his survey count is `8` which is `4+4`. Correct me if I have understood the problem incorrectly...

Comment: Yes, you got it correctly. So I would show supervisor survey count by summing up of their sales person survey count. The result is correct just issue with parentID some how. ParentID should be 0 for ABC1 & ABC2.

Comment: Do you want to me to change that thing ? it can be solved using simple if case....